# having trouble with viewing my image post in my live website

Tags: php

i mean i have this code here which uploads files with images, it worked fine on my localhost after hosting it i realise i dont get image preview but it posts perfectly well in the database

i have hosted it on a live website and as i said it worked just fine on my localhost

```
define('BASEURL', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/');

if (!empty($_FILES)){
$photo = $_FILES['description_image'];
$name = $photo['name'];
$nameArray = explode('.',$name);
$fileName = $nameArray[0];
$fileExt = $nameArray[1];
$mime = explode('/',$photo['type']);
$mimeType = $mime[0];
$mimeExt = $mime[1];
$tmpLoc = $photo['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $photo['size'];
$allowed = array('png','jpg','jpeg','gif','mp4','mp3','wma','MP4');
$uploadName = md5(microtime()).'.'.$fileExt;
$uploadPath = BASEURL.'/images/uploads/'.$uploadName;
$dbpath = '/holyfamilycatholicchurch- 
foso.com/httpdocs/images/uploads/'.$uploadName;

/*if($mimeType != 'image'){
    $errors[] = 'The file must be an image.';
}*/
/*if(!in_array($fileExt, $allowed)){
    $errors[] = 'The File extension must be a png, jpg, jpeg or gif, 
mp4, mp3, wma, MP4';
}*/
if($fileSize > 1500000000){
    $errors[] = 'The file size must be under 15MB';
}
if($fileExt != $mimeExt && ($mimeExt == 'jpeg' && $fileExt != 
'jpg')){
    $errors[] = 'File extension does not match the file.';
}
}

if(!empty($errors)){
echo display_errors($errors);   
}else{
//upload files into db
move_uploaded_file($tmpLoc,$uploadPath);
$insert_post = "INSERT INTO posts 
(`title`,`post_cat`,`description`,`description_image`,`main_content`,`date_posted`) VALUES ('$title','$post_cat','$description','$dbpath','$main_content',now())";


$insert_pst = mysqli_query($con, $insert_post);
if($insert_pst){
    echo "<script>alert('Post has been inserted')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('new_post.php?insert_product','_self') 
</script>";
}
}
}
```

i expect an output of the image

Comment: explain your question please

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your first variable:

```
define('BASEURL', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/');
```

With a standard variable declaration:

```
$BASEURL = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/" ;
```

Make sure whenever you call `$BASEURL` to have it lead with a `$`. I noticed you call `BASEURL` without a `$`.